# Rows being dropped in R with read.table?

Tags: r, read.table

I am loading a table in which the first column is a URL and reading it into R using `read.table()`.

It seems that R is dropping about 1/3 of the columns and does not return any errors.

The URLs do not contain any `#` characters or tabs (my separator field), which I understand could be an issue.  If I convert the URLs to integer IDs first, the problem goes away.

Is there something about the field that might be causing R to drop the rows?

Comment: Could you provide us with a little sample of the data (from a plain text editor, not after loaded into R)? Are you using any parameters with your read.table() or just the defaults? (PS - thanks to whoever upvoted my answer version of this comment so that I could have enough rep to comment!)

Answer (score 2):

Without a sample of the data, it's hard to say. But one small "gotcha" is that `#` is the default `comment.char` in `read.table()`. Try to set `comment.char = ""` and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your help,

Yes, so initially there were some hashes and I was able to handle them using `comment.char = ''`.  The problem turned out to be that some of my URLs contained ' and " characters.  The strangest thing about the situation is that it didn't return any errors.  After I removed these characters using tr, I had no issues with loading the data.

Comment: This should be an edit to the question.  A reproducible example is needed.